# How to call runOnUiThread in Android JNI C++

Tags: android, c++, java-native-interface

I have a method called "contactMSFServers" in Android JNI C++ which sends the post request to a API and get the JSON Returned and based on the JSON Success code i am showing toast but the problem is "contactMSFServers" is called inside a new thread using std::thread and app is crashing because Toast cant be called from background thread.

Please note:-  i dont want to get into Java,i want it to be fixed inside c++ itself.

```
void contactMSFServers(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz) {
    JavaVM *jvm;
    env->GetJavaVM(&jvm);
    jobject globalX = env->NewGlobalRef(thiz);
    std::thread([jvm, globalX]() {
        JNIEnv *threadEnv;
        JavaVMAttachArgs args;
        args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_6;
        args.name = nullptr;
        args.group = nullptr;
        if (jvm->AttachCurrentThread(&threadEnv, &args) != JNI_OK) {
            return;
        }
    
// response code stored in "success" obj.
        int success = threadEnv->CallIntMethod(obj_JSONObject, method_getInt, keySuccess);
        jstring keyEcho = threadEnv->NewStringUTF("echo");
        auto echoObj = static_cast<jstring>(threadEnv->CallObjectMethod(obj_JSONObject, method_getString, keyEcho));

        if (success == 200){
         
            
            //Below my toast method how can i put this in Ui thread ?
jclass contextClass = threadEnv->FindClass("android/content/Context");
            jmethodID applicationContextMethod = threadEnv->GetMethodID(contextClass, "getApplicationContext","()Landroid/content/Context;");
            jobject applicationContext = threadEnv->CallObjectMethod(globalX, applicationContextMethod);
            jclass toastClass = threadEnv->FindClass("android/widget/Toast");
            jmethodID makeTextMethod = threadEnv->GetStaticMethodID(toastClass, "makeText","(Landroid/content/Context;Ljava/lang/CharSequence;I)Landroid/widget/Toast;");
            jobject toast = threadEnv->CallStaticObjectMethod(toastClass, makeTextMethod, applicationContext,threadEnv->NewStringUTF("test message"), s_length);
            jmethodID showMethod = threadEnv->GetMethodID(toastClass, "show", "()V");
            threadEnv->CallVoidMethod(toast, showMethod);



        }

        threadEnv->DeleteLocalRef(obj_URL);
        threadEnv->DeleteLocalRef(obj_outputStream);
        threadEnv->DeleteLocalRef(obj_inputStream);
        threadEnv->DeleteLocalRef(byteArray);
        threadEnv->DeleteLocalRef(keySuccess);
        threadEnv->DeleteLocalRef(keyEcho);
        threadEnv->DeleteGlobalRef(globalX);
        jvm->DetachCurrentThread();

    }).detach();


}
```

I didnt tried anything because i am new to c++ and all my code is working execpt this toast issue.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is not to be using C or C++ for this kind of thing at all.  C and C++ on Android only really make sense for high performance sections of your code-  algorithms that need to run a tight loop and are CPU bound.  Think the graphics engine of a video game.  The absolute worst part of the code to write in C is anything that goes over the network-  the sole advantage of C code is speed.  When sending data across a network, the milliseconds (or more) of latency dwarf the processing time of the algorithm by a factor of 1000x at a minimum.  You're trying to speed up the wrong thing.

If you absolutely have to write this in C (which again is a horrible choice.  I mean look at how ugly and error prone this C code is for something that takes 4 easily understood lines in Java), write a function in Java that takes a string and posts that string to a Toast on the correct thread, rather than doing the threading in C.  It makes more sense that way anyway-  the threading is an artifact of the Android and Java runtime, not of the algorithm you're running here.  So let that layer care about it.  Adding it here does not increase the maintainability or ease of use of your code.  Whereas a thread agnostic post toast function would.

As for actually trying this in C-  it's ugly.  runOnUiThread takes a Runnable instance.  In Java you can create an anonymous class or lambda and the syntax is nice.  In C-  you can't do that.  You would need a Runnable class defined in Java to pass it to runOnUiThread, you can't create a new subclass in C code.  Well you can, but you'd need to write the actual Java byte code to define the class, which would be a deeper Java integration than just writing it in Java, and be very unmaintainable.  The real answer here is -  don't do this in C.

Comment: "Due to privacy reasons" you cannot have a Java helper function that does the runOnUiThread+Toast call for you? (which is what the second paragraph embodies and what would be my suggestion as well) Please explain. Especially because you already seem to have the response as a Java object...

Comment: @MaazArfi "Due to privacy reasons"-  yeah, that proves you don't know what you're talking about.

Comment: I have already solved.

Comment: Then I suggest you post a self-answer to aid others who find this question.